# Are JFE and JNE imperative to assembly, or can I remove them?

Tags: assembly, processor, cpu-architecture

I'm laying out an 8-bit processor architecture with 4-bit instructions for fun, and am encountering some limitations with a 4-bit instruction.

I'd like to include `SHR` (shift right) and `SHL` (shift left) instructions, but I don't seem to have room for them. I currently have `JGE` (jump if greater or equal), `JLE` (jump if less or equal), `JFE` (jump if equal), and `JNE` (jump if not equal), and I'm wondering if all four of these are necessary.

Are all four of these jump conditions necessary for clean code, or can I safely drop `JFE` and `JNE` for `SHR` and `SHL`?

Edit: I do have `JMP`, and it is not absolute.

Comment: Not being a hardware person but merely a low-level programmer, I wonder if you couldn't design the instruction set to take a "condition register" - jump if `FLAGS || CCREG`; yes, this means conditional jumps might be two instructions - `MOV IMM, CCREG; JC CCREG, TGT` - but it'd make the instruction set far more flexible. Same for shifts - shift by signed-const-in-reg as only one opcode. In fact, I'd probably try to encode all arithmetics/logicals as `ALUOP OPREG, SRC, TGT` if very tight on opcode slots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Carl Norum's answer, if you have support for an unconditional jump instruction (JMP), then once you have JFE you don't need its complement, JNE, since you can code that as a JFE to a JMP. Similarly, if you have JG, JFE, and JMP, you don't need JLE.

For shift, if your instruction takes an argument and that argument allows for values greater than your word size, you could use the same instruction for shift-left and shift-right and let the argument value determine if it's one or the other.

Comment: you can also get rid of the unconditional jump and keep JEQ and JNE.  the pair together makes an unconditional, or use one or the other as normal. Depending on the logic/alu operations you have you might be able to get rid of the unconditional and keep only one conditional, for example mov reg,0 followed by sub reg,reg followed by jeq is an unconditional jump.  Work through the other conditionals based on other alu/logic operations you might have.  instruction sets with like four instructions do this kind of thing

Answer (score 3):

If by "clean", you mean "easy to read", the more instructions you have, the better. Well, to a point, anyway.

In practice, you only *need* a single conditional jump instruction.

[Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) has only 8 'instructions', for example.  It has two jumps - one forward and one back, but if your processor uses an absolute jump, those could be the same.

Are you writing an assembler for your processor?  If so, you could add macro-instructions that manage the different jump forms and translate them into whatever low-level operations are actually supported by your chip.

Comment: See also [architectures with a single instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer) ;)

Comment: Yup, that's the limit.  They take readability and throw it right out the window though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of dropping JFE and JNE.

This code will branch to different locations depending on whether the test is equal (branches to definitely_equal) or not (branches to definitely_not_equal).

```
   JGE maybe_equal
   JLE definitely_not_equal
maybe_equal:
   JLE definitely_equal
   JGE definitely_not_equal
```

I'll leave it up to you to decide whether this counts as clean code or not...